# Creating text overlay on an image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to decide the best way to automate adding text overlays onto images for a resource library I am creating. I have hundreds of these kinds of resources where I grab a "sample image" of the item that I then manually, in a graphics program, add the resource name overlay. It would be great if I could just upload the image and then in the HTML add the resource name and have it overlay the name and round the corners of the image and make it look right.  An example of what I am trying to do is at http://digitallearning.pcgus.com/Pepper/PPB/General/leadership.html. This is all manual at this point and the more I can automate the better the process of creating this will be.  Thanks in advance for any advice/code I could use.

Comment: It is customary to add the relevant code you have already done, so that we can easier make suggestions or edits to what you have right now.  Now that has been said, you should create a container that is data bound to your images and is part of a loop, inside this container you will have a span or label tag with absolute positioning and a higher z-index than the image, which is also data-bound to a name entered with the image at the time of upload to your loop.

Comment: In the future I sure will, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for asking on SO!

In future, we would all appreciate it if you could add your code at the moment, if any.

There are multiple ways to do this, it all depends on how you write code.

The way I would do it is using a bootstrap row (for inline images), then insert this code (modify for your application):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="imageTextContainer">
        <div class="imagePart">
            <img src="imgSrcHere" />
        </div>
        <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="imageTextContainer">
        <div class="imagePart">
            <img src="img2SrcHere" />
        </div>
        <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="imageTextContainer">
        <div class="imagePart">
            <img src="img3SrcHere" />
        </div>
        <p>Your text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS:

```
.imageTextContainer {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #0000FF
}

.imagePart {
    height: 230px;
}

.imagePart > img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

The reason this works is because the div containing the images and text is 250px high, however the images are set to 100% of 230px, so you get 20px for text. You can obviously modify these values however

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try Monday and see where it gets me.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with that seems to have addressed my particular needs.

```css
.wrap {
  /* force the div to properly contain the floated images: */
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrap img {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  width:200px;
  height:125px;
  border:2px solid #1F497D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  z-index:1; 
}

.wrap img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(70%);
  -o-filter: brightness(70%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(70%);
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

.wrap .desc {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:55%;
  left:0;
  background-color: rgba(31,73,125,0.85);
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  font-size:11px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #111111;
  font-weight:normal;
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  bottom: -5%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Client Resources</title>
<link href="learningmat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Alice|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Alegreya:700">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="list">
  <h1 class="list2">Client Resources</h1>
  <hr class="list2">
  <p>SOME KIND OF DESCRIPTION</p>

<img src="imgs/spacer.png" class="spacer2">

<a href="docs/03 - How do we define urgency.pdf" target="_blank">
<div class="wrap">
 <img src="imgs/Urgency.jpg" />
 <h3 class="desc">How Do We Define Urgency?</h3>
</div>
</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone sees any improvements or changes, please let me know.